# Pandas aggregation groupby and min

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have the following data set and I want to return the *minimum* of `vol` grouped by `year` but I want also to know on which day (`date` column) this minimum occurred. This is a part of a bigger function.

For the example below, the return should be:

```
1997-07-14 1162876
```

[image]

The first thing I tried was:

```py
df_grouped_vol = pandas_df.groupby(pandas_df['year']).min()[['date', 'vol']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`pandas.Series.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) :

```
g = df.groupby(by="year")
​
out = df.loc[g["vol"].idxmin(), ["date", "vol"]].squeeze().values
```

Output :

```
for e in out:
    print("{} {}".format(*e))

#1997-07-14 1162876
```